# If the two-engine plane cannot take off unless both engines are operating properly, which plane is safer on takeoff?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I am practicing a bunch of probability problems I find through random sources and I am stuck with this one.

Suppose the probability that the engine in a single-engine fighter will fail on take-off is .005, and that the failure rate for an engine that is used in a two-engine fighter plane is 0.003. If the two-engine plane cannot take off unless both engines are operating properly, which plane is safer on takeoff?

The answer for the two-engine problem is .006 and I cannot fully grasp how they've arrived at this answer. I was thinking P(of both engines working properly)=1- P(at least one engine failing) but apparently this is not the answer.

P.S. Any problem recommendations similar to this problem will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

> P(of both engines working properly)=1- P(at least one engine failing)

That's correct. And P(at least one engine failing) is equal to $1 - (1 - 0.003)^2 = 0.005991$, which is $0.006$ if you don't look too closely.

Comment: oh that's such a good point, I can't believe I've overlooked that, thank you!